# Conditional Tags Worpress para aparelhos moveis

Tags: php, wordpress, if, condição

Como faço para usar uma Conditional Tag no meu tema wordpress para que um determinado script não seja carregado em aparelhos moveis.  Existe esse tipo de tag?

Se existir poderia me mostra um exemplo?

Nesse Exemplo o script so carregaria na home do site, gostaria de um codigo que ao verifica que o dipositivo é mobile o script não carregaria. ou nem apareceria no codigo fonte.

```
 <?php if( is_home() ): ?>

 <script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src=""></script>

 <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a função [`wp_is_mobile()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile):

```
<?php
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
    /* Display and echo mobile specific stuff here */
}
?>
```

Está função está presente no WordPress desde a versão 3.4. Veja mais detalhes sobre a função no [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile).

Comment: Mas o que faz essa condicional?  eu preciso que alguns scripts não seja carregados em dispositivos moveis

Comment: Ela verifica se está em um dispositivo móvel, dessa forma você pode verificar e fazer com que não carregue seus arquivos em dispositivos movies.

Comment: mostra um exemplo de como ficaria o codigo

Comment: Essa condicional não tem ajuste fino, uma biblioteca php pode ser uma boa: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/46838 - se quiser testar e incluir na resposta, fique a vontade :)

Comment: Acho que a dúvida do @user3192159 é facilmente respondida traduzindo o comment que está em inglês...

Comment: Pessoal parece que não entenderam a pergunta, eu quero simplesmente que determinado script não seja carregado em dispositivos mobiles apenas em desktop ele seria execultado